# Is there a way to escape Gremlin parameter when its name contains spaces?

Tags: gremlin

I can define a Gremlin parameter whose name contains spaces but how can I use it in a query? For example, I can have a parameter "My Parameter" but the query would fail because of the space character:

`g.addV('Person').property('Name', My Parameter)`

Comment: what's the command you used to "define a Gremlin parameter whose name contains spaces"

Comment: I am using Java API, this method in particular: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/driver/Client.html#submit-java.lang.String-java.util.Map-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you can create a parameter name with spaces, neither Gremlin Server nor any TinkerPop-enabled graph I'm aware of will be able to process the query. The server expects the parameters to behave like a standard variable. Assuming that you are sending Gremlin scripts to the server, then it is likely that your Gremlin would be processed in Groovy syntax which requires that variables not have spaces. I'm not completely sure about bytecode based requests and spaces in variable names...that might be possible if you don't use lambdas, but I would recommend just generally avoiding the practice all together.